# ERB file not replacing ENV VAR

Tags: ruby, scripting, erb

I have a simple erb file I'm trying to run and it doesn't seem to replace when I have the environment variables set:

```
<% if ENV['DEFAULT_ROUTE'] %>
default_route     : "<%= ENV['DEFAULT_ROUTE'] %>",
<% else %>
default_route     : "/dashboard/file/default.json",
<% end %>
```

I've checked the environment variable and everything *should* be working based on what I've read, however I always get the `else` printed. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

*if you can't tell I'm not a big Ruby dev*

Comment: how are you storing your environment variable?

Comment: I'm pushing to a heroku-style environment, so I'm just setting the env-vars via a CLI tool. They echo out correctly, and others being used throughout the rest of the app are fine.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate the problem so you'll need to give us more.

Comment: Can you put ```<%= p ENV %>``` just before that if block? That should print the value of ```ENV``` on the console. Maybe there is something unsetting or changing the value?

Comment: hmm... just prints out `ENV`

Comment: Can you share more of the code? In what file is this? Is this a view?

Comment: I think it's something with the server, I've ssh'd in through a tunnel and it works when I run it manually all the sudden.